# HTML5 reproducir videos de terceros (Youtube/Vimeo...)

Tags: html5, html-video

Estoy intentando añadir sources de vimeo y youtube a un reproductor de HTML5, pero me da error cuando intenta acceder al source, ¿Cual sería la forma par hacer esto?

> En youtube: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f6-MDhygWc&feature=youtu.be with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

> En Vimeo: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://vimeo.com/453371692 with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

He hecho un fragmento mínimo de código para no adjuntar todo.

```html
<video id="player" width="360" height="240">
    <source src="https://youtu.be/4f6-MDhygWc" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="https://vimeo.com/453371692" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>

<button id="play" onclick="player.play()"> Play </button>
```

Comment: El recurso no existe : https://vimeo.com/453371692c

Comment: @Elenasys ya lo corregí.

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta es muy amplia tal como está, deberías de hacer una pregunta para recursos de vimeo y otra para youtube

Comment: @RuslanLópez no creo que sea tan amplia... la pregunta podría ser bien "cómo reproducir contenido de terceros en HTML5"

Comment: Esos sitios no te van a dejar cargar sus recursos dentro de una página externa (tupagina.com). Por eso el fallo CORB. Revisa si usando el iframe como sugiere la respuesta, te lo permite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más sencilla es la de usar la herramienta para embeber de la propia plataforma.

En YouTube:

- En un ordenador, ve al vídeo de YouTube que quieras insertar.
- Debajo del vídeo, haz clic en COMPARTIR
- Haz clic en Insertar.
- En el cuadro de texto que aparece, copia el código HTML.
- Pega el código en el HTML de tu sitio web o blog.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes insertarlo en tu sitio como contenido de un `iframe`.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

Para el `autoplay`, `loop` y otras opciones puedes seguir viendo [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)